# Kendo UI Validation error message summary

Tags: jquery, error-handling, kendo-validator

I am having a some problem how to get all the error messages after validating my form with Kendo UI validation. I would like to display all the error messages on the top of form after validating.

I am using the following code to validate "$("#YourFormName").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator").validate()".

I am looking for somekind of answer than i can use project wide by just including a code section into all my forms.

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt. Did you check the example on https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/validator/custom-validation?

Comment: thx for suggestion, I actually found the solution I was looking for at https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator/methods/errors